# Nonexisten function apply_impulse in base Node2D

Tags: documentation, game-development, godot, gdscript

Why when I run it to my app has been closed and write it - Nonexisten function apply_impulse in base Node2D. I see Godot's doc and I find it method and your parent is RigidBidy2D, but I do this code by the video and he use KinematicBody2D and it is alright

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var movespeed = 500 
var bulletspeed = 2000
var bullet = preload("res://Bullet.tscn") 

func _ready():
    pass 

func _physics_process(delta):
    var motion = Vector2()
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed('up'):
        motion.y -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('down'):
        motion.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('right'):
        motion.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('left'):
        motion.x -= 1
    
    motion = motion.normalized() 
    motion = move_and_slide(motion * movespeed) 
    
    look_at(get_global_mouse_position())

    if Input.is_action_just_pressed('LMB'):
        fire()

func fire():
    var bullet_instance = bullet.instance()
    bullet_instance.position = get_global_position()
    bullet_instance.rotation_degrees = rotation_degrees
    bullet_instance.apply_impulse(Vector2(), Vector2(bulletspeed, 0).rotated(rotation))
    get_tree().get_root().call_deferred("add_child", bullet_instance)
```

Comment: Could you please show rhe error stack?

Answer (score 0):

As you have found `apply_impulse` exists in `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`).

Your presented code uses `apply_impulse`, here:

```
bullet_instance.apply_impulse(Vector2(), Vector2(bulletspeed, 0).rotated(rotation))
```

---

If that works, it implies that `bullet_instance` must be a `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`). Let us see where do you define `bullet_instance`:

```
var bullet_instance = bullet.instance()
```

This means that `bullet_instance` is an instance of the `PackedScene` you refer as `bullet`. Well, that scene must be a `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`). Let us see where do you define `bullet`:

```
var bullet = preload("res://Bullet.tscn")
```

Thus, `"res://Bullet.tscn"` must be a `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`). More precisely, the root node of that scene must be a `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`).

---

On the other hand, if this line (or some other similar line) does not work:

```
bullet_instance.apply_impulse(Vector2(), Vector2(bulletspeed, 0).rotated(rotation))
```

And you are getting the error "Nonexistent function 'apply_impulse' in base Node2D", then it means that your are calling `apply_impulse` on a `Node2D` but not `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`).

In this case it would mean that `bullet_instance` is an instance of `Node2D` but not `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`). And then the same process as before would lead us to the root node of `"res://Bullet.tscn"` being an instance of `Node2D` but not `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`).

---

Thus, double check `"res://Bullet.tscn"`. The type of the root node must be `RigidBody` (or `RigidBody2D`) for `apply_impulse` to work on it.

---

To be clear, if you call `apply_impuse` like this:

```
apply_impulse(Vector2(), Vector2(bulletspeed, 0).rotated(rotation))
```

Or like this:

```
self.apply_impulse(Vector2(), Vector2(bulletspeed, 0).rotated(rotation))
```

Then you are calling it on the node that has the script where that is written (which is a `KinematicBody2D` in this case, which does not have `apply_impulse`, and thus that would not work).

---

To reiterate, when you write `object.function(...)`, you are calling `function` on that `object`. If you write `self.function(...)`, then you are calling `function` on the object that has the script where you write that. If you write simply `function(...)`, that is the same as `self.function(...)`.

Just in case, I'll also mention that the above applies if you use `$`. For example `$object.function(...)` would be calling `function` on a child node called "object".

And for that code to work, the object on which you call the function must have it.